# How to rename file by replacing substring using batch in Windows

Tags: windows, string, file, batch-file, rename

I want to rename file name like *"how-to-**rename**-file.jpg"* to *"how-to-**reuse**-file.jpg"*  by using a Windows batch file

I.e. I only want to replace one or two words in a file name.

Comment: Please add what you have tried. Also, we need more information.

Comment: Consider trying [Bulk Rename Here](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php).

Comment: @casperOne hmmm...a little too strict me thinks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
@echo off

Set "Filename=how-to-rename-file.jpg"
Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"

REM Call Rename "%Filename%" "%%Filename:%Pattern%=%Replace%%%"

Call Echo %%Filename:%Pattern%=%Replace%%%
:: Result: how-to-reuse-file.jpg

Pause&Exit
```

I give you other example for a loop of files:

> UPDATE:

I've missed some things in the syntax 'cause fast-typing my last edit, here is the corrected code:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"

For %%# in ("C:\Folder\*.jpg") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

PS: You can read here to learn more about substring: 
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Comment: The second code  is exactly what i need. Thank you sooo much for your help.  Also thanks for providing me link to learn more about strings I found this link very informative :-)

Comment: Why did you use `Set "File=%%~nx#"` instead of a simple Set `"File=%%#"` ?

Comment: @Marco Demaio To introduce new users in the reserved For modifiers.

Comment: @ElektroStudios sorry, but what do you mean by "introduce new users"? What users?

Comment: Everyone who is starting to learn, those who come here in search of a solution and finds a public code.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: ah ok, sorry, I thought you were talking about users' rights in Windows OS. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work to replace 'special' characters such as ç or õ.

Answer (score 37):

The code above doesn't rename the files - The paths are an issue and the source filename is incorrect.

This will work on files in the current folder - except those with ! in the names will be a problem.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"

For %%a in (*.jpg) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but what should I add to define a folder instead of using the local folder?

Comment: Place `pushd "c:\folder"` above the loop, or use `cd /d "c:\folder"`

Comment: It works like a charm! Great stuff!

Comment: Just one note, I think `Set "File=%%~a"` can be replaced with `Set "File=%%a"` (with no ~) because the ~ is used with a parameter extension that you are not using. http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: @MarcoDemaio  You are absolutely correct that the tilda is not needed, though it will never cause any issue there either.

Comment: @foxidrive Your solution is an absolute beauty. Very precise and simple to understand. Helped me a great deal.

Comment: This works really neat!!

Comment: This worked great. Now could you make it recursive on subfolders?

Comment: @RodrigoZuluaga  I'm curious how you guys made it work. I tried all that is posted above. No luck for me.

Comment: @enigma6205 create a in notepad a yourname.bat file, place that top code, and put the file where the files you're renaming are. If you don't wanna mess around with bat files u can download Bulk Rename Utility. I don't think im allowed to to place url here, so search it on google, the site is a .co.uk. I found this and replaced all my bat files for masive renaming.