# Rename folder by replacing sub-string using bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

Found this- [How to rename file by replacing substring using batch in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128869/how-to-rename-file-by-replacing-substring-using-batch)   it does the exact thing I am looking for.but, I want this for a FOLDER,not a file. I am tired to manage it for a Folder. Please do help. I want to make a search in the current folder(%CD) and replace all the folder names containing "MyImage" sub-string with "HerImage" substring.

Comment: change for command to `for /D ....` and replace *.jpg with *

Comment: C:\Folder\ is not the path that I want. I want to do it using %CD% . Is there any way?

Comment: It works .It works!!!!! But please please tell me what to do exactly If I want to supply the current dir path instead of c:\Folder\

Comment: %cd%\* was what I needed. :)