# How to replace all spaces by underscores in all file names of a folder?

Tags: windows, replace, cmd

I'm trying to rename all the files inside a folder (all .exe files). I want to replace all the spaces with underscores, e.g. `qwe qwe qwe asd.exe` to `qwe_qwe_qwe_asd.exe`.

I need to do this using the command line. I tried a lot of possible solutions I found on internet and even on this site, but I can't make it work.

I also need to do this in "one single line" / "one command", but I'll accept all the working answers.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A one liner

```
cmd /e:on /v:on /c "for %f in ("* *.exe") do (set "n=%~nxf" & set "n=!n: =_!" & ren "%~ff" "!n!" )"
```

Spawn a cmd instance, with extensions and delayed expansion enabled, and for each exe file with spaces in name, replace spaces with underscores and rename the file with the new name

Comment: How do you modify this to do it recursively through subfolders?

Comment: @AlexR, replace `for %f` by `for /r %f`…

Comment: @Champion Perfect Solution

Comment: How do you run this in batch file? thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Adapted from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129486/2000557

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern= "
Set "Replace=_"

For %%a in (*.exe) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

Create a batch file (`*.bat`) with the above contents. Place that batch file in the folder with all the .exe's and it will replace the spaces with underscores when you run it.

Comment: thanks for answering, but i cannot use a batch file.. I need to use a single command..

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga You can run for loop directly from CMD - there is just 1 '%' sign, e.g.:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`for %i in (*.css) do ( ren "%~i" "_%~i.scss" )`
=> rename all files with .css extension to "_ORIGINALFILENAME.scss"

Comment: give me access denied

Comment: @CristiánVargasAcevedo sounds like a file permission error to me.

Answer (score 12):

Simple as:

```
set filename=qwe qwe qwe asd.exe
set filename=%filename: =_%
```

Comment: how does that rename files?

Comment: `set filename=qwe qwe qwe asd.exe`, `set filename2=%filename: =_%`, `ren "filename" "filename2"`

Comment: works only as long as the original file name is "qwe qwe qwe asc.exe"

Answer (score 9):

Using forfiles:

```
forfiles /m *.exe /C "cmd /e:on /v:on /c set \"Phile=@file\" & if @ISDIR==FALSE ren @file !Phile: =_!"
```

Add `/s` after `forfiles` to recurse through subfolders.

Comment: In case you want to change spaces to dashes or dashes to underscores the bit that controls the "turn this into that" logic is `Phile: =_!`. Whatever comes before the `=` is what will be replaced. The thing that goes after the `=` is what it will be replaced with.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Gray answer, I have extending it to replace filenames recursively in all subdirectories.

File 1: *replace.bat*

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pattern= "
set "replace=_"

for %%I in (*.ext) do (
    set "file=%%~I"
    ren "%%I" "!file:%pattern%=%replace%!"
)
```

File 2: *recursive.bat*

```
for /d /r . %%D in (*) do (
    copy replace.bat "%%D\replace.bat"
    cd "%%D"
    replace.bat
    del replace.bat
    cd..
)
```

**Files**

- `replace.bat` contains script to replace `space` with `underscore`
- `recursive.bat` contains script to do recursion in all subdirectories

**How to use?**

- Save both `replace.bat` and `recursive.bat` in same directory.
- Replace `.ext` with desired file extension to match (like `.mp4`) in `replace.bat`.
- Double click (run) ONLY `recursive.bat` file.

Comment: this only works if I manually copy the replace.bat in all subfolders. Which is quite a pain. What should i add to manually copy the replace.bat to all subfolders?

Comment: please follow **how to use** section

Comment: Mhm, I see so you assume theres only one subdirectory. In my case the directory contains many subdirectories each with a subdirectory with a file I want to rename. Do I still have to copy both the replace and recursive bat files to each of them?

Comment: Place `replace.bat` and `recursive.bat` in parent directory, it'll work on all child directories.

Answer (score 1):

set data=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set data=%data: =0%

Comment: Loved this! Exactly what I needed to get spaces out of string.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following 2 commands in a `.bat` file. It will replace `" "` with `"_"` in all files and folders, recursively, starting from the folder where the file is stored.

```
forfiles /s /m *.* /C "cmd /e:on /v:on /c set \"Phile=@file\" & if @ISDIR==FALSE ren @file !Phile: =_!"
forfiles /s /C "cmd /e:on /v:on /c set \"Phile=@file\" & if @ISDIR==TRUE ren @file !Phile: =_!"
```

Note: First line is doing this for files, and second one is doing this for folders. Each line can be used separately.

Comment: This is the only answer that I tried that worked for me; Works on files AND directories; Only needs 1 file, not 2. Not sure why it had zero upvotes or comments...?

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweak to Hamza Rashid's answer. Specifically his recursive.bat script.

recursive.bat

```
set orig=%cd%

for /d /r . %%D in (*) do (
    copy replace.bat "%%D\replace.bat"
    cd "%%D"
    replace.bat
    del replace.bat
    cd %orig%
)
```

replace.bat stays the same and the instructions stay the same.