# Batch File to replace spaces with dashes (-) in a filename

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to replace spaces in image files and with dashes (-), for example:

```
this is a file.png
```

becomes

```
this-is-a-file.png
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "root_dir=c:\somewhere"
pushd "%root_dir%"
for %%a in ("* *.png") do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "f_name=%%~nxa"
    set "cf_name=!f_name: =-!"
    ren "%%~nxa" "!cf_name!"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

Check also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) (which in your case will not apply)

Comment: The script will be more efficient if the FOR loop uses `"* *"` for the file mask.

Comment: Delayed expansion must be toggled on and off within the loop if any names contain `!`.

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet will do

```
cmd /e:on /v:on /c "for %f in ("* *.txt") do (set "n=%~nxf" & set "n=!n: =-!" & ren "%~ff" "!n!" )"
```

> Input: New Text Document.txt
>
> Output: New-Text-Document.txt

Give credit to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791264/cmd-windows-replace-spaces-with-underscores)