# Want to understand a for loop statement of bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"

For %%a in (*.jpg) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

This renames .jpg having substring `rename` .Ref: [How to rename file by replacing substring using batch in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128869/how-to-rename-file-by-replacing-substring-using-batch) Can anyone make me understand, How the `For loop` does this job? Additionally: is it possible to use a `/f` switch here, to get rid of `Access Denied` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop in your example will loop through each file ending with `.jpg` in the current directory.

Every iteration of the loop `%%a` will expand to the name of the current `.jpg` file.

The rename command then changes the name of `%%a` (current `.jpg` file) to a specified name, which is a modified version of the `!File!` variable.

`"!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"` - this is string manipulation - see [DOS Tips](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php). It will expand to the contents of the variable `!File!` where `%Pattern%` equals `%Replace%`.

So if you had the variable `%test%` which you have set to equal `"Test_1_variable"` and you run `echo %test:_= %` it will output `Test 1 variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Test this: it uses a for /f so that the files aren't renamed twice.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg ') Do (
Set "File=%%~na"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~xa"
)
```