# Renaming file names with a BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

Need to edit the file names of set of video files in a single folder in Windows 7.

Interested in a simple way to do the following modification to set of file names

Replace the "." with the character "x"

```
eg. 
   original: 04.19 - Lady & Peebles.mp4
   renamed:  04x19 - Lady & Peebles.mp4
```

What is a suitable way to do this manually using a Batch file?

Comment: Do you have to use a batch file? I can do it in C#

Comment: @ThatWeirdo, Not everyone knows C#.. like me! But Batch is easier for me in this case, without the compiling overhead.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the "." I'm referring to is the first one, not the file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d/b *.mp4') do (
    set "$File=%%~na"
    echo ren "%%a" "!$file:.=x!%%~xa"
)
```

The `echo` is included so that you can test the output. If it's OK remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Folder=C:\Folder\*.mp4"

Set "Pattern=."
Set "Replace=x"

FOR %%# IN ("%Folder%") DO (
    SET "File=%%~nx#"
    REN "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

SET "Pattern=xmp4"
SET "Replace=.mp4"

FOR %%# IN ("%Folder%") DO (
    SET "File=%%~nx#"
    REN "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

PAUSE&EXIT
```

Source: [How to rename file by replacing substring using batch in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128869/how-to-rename-file-by-replacing-substring-using-batch)

Do some research next time please.

Comment: @SS' Did you change the `Folder` variable to the correct path? @ThatWeirdo There's no need for the second renaming - instead of `%%~nx#`, you can use `%%~n#` which will get the name of the file without the extension. You can then tack on the extension at the end. Take a look at the answer from @sachadee.

Answer (score 0):

Have the first dot *ALL* the files? If so, then this command-line do the desired rename:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %a in ('dir /B *.mp4') do ren "%a.%b.%c" "%ax%b.%c"
```

If you insert previous line in a Batch file, then double the percent signs.