# Change file names with .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi guys I'm new to batch and have a question for my .bat to rename files.

I looked at the following solution and tried to transfer this to my problem:
[Renaming file names with a BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229916/renaming-file-names-with-a-bat-file)

So my .bat looks like this one:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1
set padded_count=000!count!
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
    ren "%%a" !padded_count!.txt
    set /a count+=1
)
```

And I have a file with random names for .txt data.
E.g.

```
abc.txt
def.txt
123.txt
456.txt
```

And I want to change these into:

```
0001.txt
0002.txt
...
```

But when I use my .bat its just the first .txt which changes its name.
Can you explain me why? And what should I do to get all of these.

Or is it possible to handle this problem with REN in cmd with something like "ren *.txt ___"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment on the requirement, This is similar to @Magoo's answer, but I am not limiting it to 4 chars.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=10000
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
    if "!count:~1!" == "9999" set count=100000
    set /a count+=1
    echo ren "%%a" !count:~1!.txt
)
```

In this instance, once we get to 9999 we set a new `count` variable so out files will continue with an additional digit.

```
ren "file9999.txt" 9999.txt
ren "file10000.txt" 00001.txt
ren "file10001.txt" 00002.txt
...
```

Comment: Hi Gerhard, now I understand. It works fine, thank you so much for your detailed answer.

Comment: I see that there is a problem with that solution maybe it was not clear from my side. When I have >10 .txt data sets, I expect 0010 instead of 00010 (which is currently the case). Maybe I should combine it with Magoo's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=10001
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
    ren "%%a" !count:-4!.txt
    set /a count+=1
)
```

where `!count:-4!` selects the final 4 characters of `count`.