# Alter Batch Script to Recursively Alter All File Types

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to modify the code below to recursively rename all file types, not just a single type, within all subdirectories:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"
For %%# in ("C:\Folder\*.jpg") Do (
Set "File=%%~nx#"
Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
Pause&Exit
```

Source:
[How to rename file by replacing substring using batch in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128869/how-to-rename-file-by-replacing-substring-using-batch-in-windows)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `*.jpg` --> `*.*`, and `for` --> `for /R`;

Comment: Hmmm. Not working. Did I add correctly?

For /R in ("C:\Users\HTPC\Desktop\test\*.*") Do (

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification and if you found that the results are what you expected, just get rid from `echo` before the command `Ren`

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"
Set "MyFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\test\*.*"
For %%# in ("%MyFolder%") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    echo Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
Pause>nul & Exit
```