# create batch file based on date in file name and move files

Tags: batch-file

I have a large number of excel files with filenames that all end in a timestamp that looks like this:

examplefile_2018_08_24_110222.xlsx

I would like to move all of these files based on the month and year of the timestamp, but I would like the folder name to be the previous month. So for the above example, I would want to create a folder named July2018 and move that file into that folder. Is it possible to do this with a batch file?

Comment: So are you saying you want to rename the file: **examplefile_2018_08_24_110222.xlsx** to **July2018.xlsx** and move it into a folder named July2018?  That is how I am interpreting your description.

Comment: no sorry I mistyped -- edited my post to fix that. I don't need to rename the file. I want to make a folder based on the date in the file name, but name the folder the previous month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you need it to do. I added some comments so please let me know if you do not understand a line of the code.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM get a list of the files
FOR %%F IN (*.xlsx) DO (
    REM GET 2nd, 3rd and 4th parts of file name: examplefile_2018_08_24_110222.xlsx
    FOR /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=_" %%G IN ("%%~F") DO (
        REM GET previous month and/or year
        FOR /F "delims=" %%J IN ('powershell "(Get-Date %%H/%%I/%%G).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMMMyyyy')"') DO (
            REM make the directory
            md "%%J" >nul 2>&1
            REM move the file
            move "%%~F" "%%J\"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you! Thanks for the comments in the code -- I'm VERY new to batch scripts and the breakdown helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow this previous question: [How to rename file by replacing substring using batch in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128869/how-to-rename-file-by-replacing-substring-using-batch-in-windows)

That question is more of a "find and replace" batch file question but might serve you well. In your case, it seems like you may want to find and replace:

`2018_08` with `July2018`,

`2018_09` with `August2018`

etc.

The issue here is the amount of cases and loops needed.

---

### For example this would be 3 months:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Location=C:\Users\Example"

Set "Pattern=2018_08"
Set "Replace=July2018"

For %%# in ("%Location%\*.xlsx") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Set "Pattern=2018_09"
Set "Replace=August2018"

For %%# in ("%Location%\*.xlsx") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Set "Pattern=2018_10"
Set "Replace=September2018"

For %%# in ("%Location%\*.xlsx") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

**Note that C:\Users\Example would be replaced with your desired folder.**

Comment: thank you for your answer -- I mistyped in my question. I'm not trying to change the filename but rather use the filename to get the date, then create a folder that is the month previous to the one in the filename. Then I want to move that file into that folder.