# Making a batch file to transfer files with a filename containing specific numbers

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am trying to create a batch file that allows me to transfer files with a FILENAME containing specific numbers. I have thousands of files that have filename in a certain format - with dates at the end (i.e. `abc010118.txt`) - that I would like to archive.

*Note: the files were created/last modified on the same date, and hence the filename is the only thing that can be used to differentiate one another

Having never studied programming, I searched and tried different things for hours to come up to writing this cmd:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\*122718. /ad /b') do robocopy "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\%a" "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\dest\%a" /e /v /np /w:1 /r:1 /xo
```

What I would like to add to my command is to repeat the same action as the one that my command is performing, but with an increment of 100. For example, I would like the files containing the string `010118` at the end to move to another directory and then move files with their name containing the string `010218` to move to another directory and so on.

I would really appreciate any feedback and suggestions on this. Please know that I am completely new to programming and would really appreciate if anyone could give a detailed explanation of each line.

Comment: You might find the search phrase `[batch-file] increment number` (with the brackets)  useful to help you get started. Use the search box at the top of the page.

Comment: Are all the files located in (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\\) ..?

Comment: Would be quite tedious to select every number combination. I suggest to use Substrings to extract day,month,year - check if a correspondent folder exits (create if neccessary) and move the file. There **ARE** examples here on [SO]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create batch file based on date in file name and move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804897/create-batch-file-based-on-date-in-file-name-and-move-files)

Comment: All files are located in C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\, but in different folders within that directory.

Comment: I've failed in trying to find in stack overflow to figure out if there's any other post with the same problem. If I am missing something, I would really appreciate directing me to other posts.

Comment: Did you solve this issue or do you still need guidance?

Comment: Still working on it...